# Bind Telerik treeview to Telerik Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, telerik, telerik-mvc

How to bind Telerik MVC TreeView to a Telerik MVC Grid in RAZOR engine. I got a dashboard which has a Telerik MVC Grid bound with single column data ie only one column in a Grid. And I need to bind Telerik MVC TreeView to each Item in the Grid ie each cell. ie each cell in the Telerik Grid should be shown in TreeView, just as shown below :

[image: Screenshot of Telerik TreeView data bound to Telerik Grid]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible out of the box. But you can use templates:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/templates

You can use ClientTemplate for column and load treeview to it by ajax from another child view. Downloading is started on RowDataBound event.

Example:
**GridView**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onRowDataBound(e) {
    var grid = $(this).data('tGrid');
        var dataItem = e.dataItem;
        var replacement = $('div.e-marker-detailarea', e.detailRow);

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetTreeView", "SomeController")',
                data: {value: dataItem.TreeViewValue},
                type: 'POST',
                error: function() {
                    alert("Error!!!")
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) { replacement.html(data); }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

```
@(
Html.Telerik().Grid<GridModel>()
        .Name("GridModel")
        .DataBinding(b=>b.Ajax().Select("GridBind", "SomeController"))
        .Columns(columns=>
            {
                columns.Bound(b => b.TreeViewValue).Title("Комментарий").ClientTemplate("<div class=\"e-marker-detailarea\"></div>");
            })
        .ClientEvents(c => c.OnRowDataBound("onRowDataBound"))
)
```

**ChildTreeView**:

```
@{
  Html.Telerik().TreeView()
    .Name("TreeView")
    .Items(item =>
    {
        item.Add()
            .Text("Mail")
            .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mail.gif")
            .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Mail Icon" })
            .Items(subItem =>
            {
                subItem.Add()
                        .Text("Personal Folders")
                        .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/mailPersonalFolders.gif")
                        .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Personal Folders Icon" });
            });
        item.Add()
            .Text("Contacts")
            .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/contacts.gif")
            .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Contacts Icon" })
            .Items((subItem) =>
            {
                subItem.Add()
                        .Text("My Contacts")
                        .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/contactsItems.gif")
                        .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Contact Icon" });

            });
        item.Add()
            .Text("Tasks")
            .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/tasks.gif")
            .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Tasks Icon" })
            .Items((subItem) =>
            {
                subItem.Add()
                        .Text("My Tasks")
                        .ImageUrl("~/Content/PanelBar/FirstLook/tasksItems.gif")
                        .ImageHtmlAttributes(new { alt = "Task Icon" });                   
            });
    })
}
```

**Controller**:

```
ActionResult GridView()
{
    return View();
}
[GridAction]
ActionResult GridBind()
{
    //initialize IEnumerable<GridModel> gridModelList
    return View(new GridModel(gridModelList));
}

ActionResult GetTreeView(TreeViewValue treeViewValue)
{
    //some calculations to get model
    return PartialView("ChildTreeView", model)
}
```

Comment: is it not possible ? you mean treeview cannot be bound inside each item in the Telerik Grid ??????

Comment: It is possible through templates. If you read demos of telerik you will know how

Comment: No way, this is near impossible even with templates.

Comment: It's possible. I write example in answer. You can use ClientTemplate for collumn and load treeview to it by ajax from another child view. Downloading is started on RowDataBound event.